# How to make a div full height of remaining space on screen

Tags: html, css

I've recently published my new website but on larger resolution monitors my 2nd content div which comes under my navigation and a small piece of text only expands to the size of the content within it which is fine except from one page where there is very little content meaning there is a large white section between it and the page footer.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XUuVL/

I was wondering how I could make it so that the grey area would fill that whitespace left underneath it.

Cheers.

```
html,body 
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font: 0.74em Arial;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#content
{
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 5% 20px 5%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content2
{
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 60px 5% 20px 5%;
    background: #808080;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since `body` and `#wrapper` have 100% height, you cannot give height in percentage to children elements. It would work if you give fixed height i.e. height in percentage to `#wrapper`.

You can give gray color to `body` and give white color to `#content`.

Answer (score 0):

add **position: absolute** in your content2 ... i hope you will want like this...

```
 #content2
    {
        position:absolute;
        width: 90%;
        min-width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 60px 5% 20px 5%;
        background: #808080;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/XUuVL/2/
.
Using `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `wrapper` element the same `background` and the bottom `box-shadow` as `content2`. Then it will look like `content2` extends to the bottom. You must also give it the same `width`

```
#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background: #808080;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #000000;
}
```

Now you remove the bottom `box-shadow` from `content2` and give a white background to the `content` element

```
#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#content2 {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #000000;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUuVL/3/)

Comment: This sorted the issue, thanks very much. Have to make do without the box-shadow at the bottom because I have a footer as well, but other than that it's perfect.